# Dates in google sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, formula

I am very new at all of this, and I don't know if what I want to do is even possible, but I'm hoping someone can assist me with some formulas if it is.

I am trying to create a spreadsheet for my business's scheduling purposes. I have created a spreadsheet that lists my PO's, start date, end date, location, project hours, and total days.

I currently have a couple formulas on the sheet. When I enter the project hours in column e the formula =roundup(E2/24) inputs the expected total days of work into column f.

I have a starting date of 7/1/2022 entered in b2 then have a formula that looks at column c (end date) and adds the amount of days from column f (total days) to the end date. Each line there after copies the end date from the row above to the start date and then adds the total days from f to that to complete the next row.

What I would like to do is have the dates only reflect workdays (M-F) instead of returning all dates. Is this even possible?

Take a look at spreadsheet example, but it is pretty basic.

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to add "Total days" to the "Start Date" to get the "End Date" excluding weekends, in this case Sundays and Saturdays.

Paste this formula in cell `C2` "End Date" column.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(E2:E="",,WORKDAY.INTL(B2:B,F2:F,"0000011",)))
```

[image]

Breakdown:

1 - [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) output's values into several rows and/or columns, and to make the formula dynamic.

2 - [`WORKDAY.INTL`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3294972?hl=en) determines the date after a certain number of workdays, excluding certain number of weekends and holidays.

3 - `[weekend]` argument using string method of ones and zeros `"0000011"` to specify workdays and weekends, `0` workday, `1` weekends starting from Monday to Sunday.

here is the link to the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1upsBH5zDWNPekVY2rMxRmWlxr_fb0B16XcIDn2eMWVw/edit?usp=sharing), hope that answerd your question.

Comment: This is amazing and worked absolutely perfectly for what I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Kato22 YEY! If you are satisfied with the answer, don't forget to accept it.